# Is using INCLUDES script for the header and footer good with SEO?

Tags: include

I wanted to use the INCLUDES script that will grab external html and place it in a page.  I was thinking of using this for the header and footer for every page.

Is this a good idea?  Will it interfere with SEO?

I hate to have to change every footer and header on every page if there is an edit.

Is there a better approach?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person (or search engine) viewing the page can't tell whether you've used server side includes or not.  Make a useful site and the googles will come.